# Combobox does not stay open in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, combobox

I have a problem with the combo boxes of my application (written in C, built in Visual Studio 2012) running in Windows 8.

If I click on the little black arrow of the combo box the list shows up, but closes immediately when I release the mouse button. So the list is open as long I hold the mouse button down. This means it is not possible to click on (and so select) an item in the list!

It only happens when the combo box is in a modal window. In a not-modal window the combo box works fine, but I need it in a modal window as well.

In Windows 7 the exactly same application works fine. The combo box stays open (after clicking on the arrow and release the mouse button) until I clicked on one of the items in the list.
Running the application in Windows 7 compatibility mode, does not solve the issue on a Windows  8 machine. 
When I compare Windows messages after clicking on the arrow to open the list, I see in Windows 8 the message WM_COMMAND with notification code CBN_SELENDOK, after WM_CAPTURECHANGED. This could explain why the list closes, but why do I get this message form Windows?
Or does anyone has another idea how to solve the issue?